# Ubuntu Cannot download file from a server to local directory

Tags: server, ssh, lubuntu

I made a dump on my server's database and it was saved successfully.

I am using this command to try to download this file to my Desktop:

```
scp root@138.68.146.22:dblocal.sql.gz ~/Desktop
```

However after typing my password, the file is not downloaded and on the terminal its name is displayed.

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text, I suspect you may have better results with `sudo`  (your user probably doesn't have permissions to save a file owned by root)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure, but I think you have to use the full path to your db file in the scp command. Additionally it is not very nice to download files to your Desktop folder. I would for example suggest the following command:

```
scp root@138.68.146.22:/fullpath-to-your-file ~/Download
```

This also presumes that root login is permitted on the the remote site. If not, you have to use another user, and ensure that this user has rights to read the db file.